# I am trying to pass values from HTML input into a JavaScript function and then to an apex controller to create a lead in salesforce

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce, parameter-passing, apex

- HTML (here is where I am collecting the information on an experience builder page)

  ```
           <div class="slds-form-element__control ">
          <input type="text"
           id="firstName"
           placeholder="First Name"
           class="first_name_input slds-input"
            />                 
           </div>

           <div class="slds-form-element__control ">
           <input type="text"
            id="lastName"
            placeholder="Last Name"
            class="last_name_input slds-input"
            />     

           </div>

           <div class="slds-form-element__control ">
           <input type="text"
            id="email"
            placeholder="Email Address"
            class="email_input slds-input"
            />                 
           </div>
  ```

-JavaScript (the values are passed to java script where there are multiple functions, this is the function that is designed to pass the values to apex for lead creation)

```
createLead(firstName,lastName, email) {
            var firstName = firstName
            var lastName = lastName
            var email = email
            this.createOrObtainExistingLead()
            this.navigateToFAPage()
            }
```

-Apex(once values are passed to the apex controller the lead should be created with values passed from JavaScript)

public class VOQuickQuoteController {

```
@AuraEnabled
@future
public static void createOrObtainExistingLead(string firstName, string lastName, string email,) {    
    
    Lead l = new Lead(
        firstName=firstName,
        lastName=lastName,
        email=email,       
    );
    insert l;    
}
```

}